# Efficiently applying a function on whole dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, apply

i want to apply a function to the columns of this dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"a":[0,1,2,3,4,5,6], "b": [10,100,100,100,100,1000,1]})

def scale(values):
    scaled_values = (values - np.min(values)) / (np.max(values) - np.min(values))
    return scaled_values / np.sum(scaled_values)
```

This function requires to consider all values in the column at once. Thus i cannot apply the function with the "apply" method of pandas. Thus at the moment i just call

```
df.loc[:,"a"] = scale(df["a"])
df.loc[:,"b"] = scale(df["b"])
```

However, if i have a lot of columns i don't want to do it like this and also looping over the columns is quite ugly:

```
for c in df.columns:
  df.loc[:,c] = scale(df[c])
```

I'm wondering if there is a pandas method to "apply" a method to the whole column at once so that i can get rid of this ugly loop. Any suggestions?

Comment: "*I'm wondering if there is a pandas method to "apply" a method to the whole column at once so that i can get rid of this ugly loop. Any suggestions?*", how is it not a duplicate? ;)

Comment: @mozway - ya, Im thinking about `Efficiently applying a function on whole dataframe column`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it called [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) for processing function by each column:

```
#default axis=0
df = df.apply(scale)
#df = df.apply(scale, axis=0)

print (df)
          a         b
0  0.000000  0.006410
1  0.047619  0.070513
2  0.095238  0.070513
3  0.142857  0.070513
4  0.190476  0.070513
5  0.238095  0.711538
6  0.285714  0.000000
```

Here is possible pass all columns together - so performance is better:

```
df = scale(df)
#alternative
df = df.pipe(scale)
print (df)
          a         b
0  0.000000  0.006410
1  0.047619  0.070513
2  0.095238  0.070513
3  0.142857  0.070513
4  0.190476  0.070513
5  0.238095  0.711538
6  0.285714  0.000000
```

**Performance**:

```
#[70000 rows x 20 columns]
df = pd.concat([df] * 10000, ignore_index=True)
df = pd.concat([df] * 10, axis=1, ignore_index=True)


In [72]: %timeit df.apply(scale)
57.3 ms ± 3.32 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [73]: %timeit df.pipe(scale)
38.5 ms ± 241 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [74]: %timeit scale(df)
38.6 ms ± 780 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: i'm confused: whats the difference between df.apply()  and df.apply(lambda x: scale(x), axis=1)  then? cause the 2nd version is calling the function multiple times. Always thought thats the same :/

Comment: @J-H - difference is `df = df.apply(scale)` is same like `df = df.apply(scale, axis=0)`

Comment: oh i see, maybe it would have helped to check the docs. Sry its still early here :) Thanks for the tip with "pipe" never used that before